# Is a "Never tell your password to anyone" message in chat really necessary?

Tags: usability, password, security, messages, chat

In almost every chat window I open, there's this fairly obvious statement:

```
Never tell your [password/credit card/social security/etc] to anyone.
```

Are there some **standards for chat functionality** that require this statement be put in place? Is it there to prevent liability when their account is inevitably hacked when they do share their password?

This statement seems obvious enough to warrant omitting it - why actually include it in every single chat dialogue?

Comment: Would be reasonable to assume these are there for the same reasons "are you really 18?" questions are there in porn / booze / tobacco sites -- shifting blame, in case of any legal trouble.

Comment: You can't fix stupid, is 'Caution this Coffee is really hot and will burn you!!!' really necessary on coffee cups? Yes, because it wasn't there and someone filed a law suit over it.

Comment: Even if it seems obvious to you, it's not obvious to everyone - when I managed a corporate IT helpdesk, about every week someone would drop off a computer with a sticky note with their password or send the password in an email. When we tell the users not to do that their common reply is "Well what's the harm, you're IT so you can get into the computer anyway" (which is true, so we don't need the password!).

Comment: [hunter2](http://www.bash.org/?244321). Oh, and, @ryan, try educating yourself about the McDonald's hot coffee case: it's considerably more complicated than you might imagine.

Comment: @TRiG I have read up on the entire case, and what I said was a gross over simplification, but it doesn't make that trend any less true. There are instructions on pop-tarts that say remove from foil before putting in toaster, or on hot-pockets after they come out of the microwave it says in **big bold letters: CAUTION CONTENTS ARE HOT**... They are called *Hot Pockets* and I just put them in the microwave, thank you for the warning that they might be hot... Can you really say that that warning is there for any other reason then to cover the companies liability? Can you really say that?

Comment: Another aspect of not telling anyone your password in chat is logging. Even if you trust the person, the chat might still be logged both on your end, their end and possibly on the server end. No one wants their passwords stored in log files anywhere, but they might not realize that this could happen just by sending it in a chat.

Comment: [Bags of peanuts pulled from stores for not having "warning: contains peanuts" sign...](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-manchester-22308165)

Comment: @vartec Actually, this was a bag of monkey nuts. Peanuts are a type of bean, not nut -- people can be allergic to peanuts but not nuts, and vice versa. That's why 'mixed nuts' will say 'contains peanuts'.

Comment: @Brendon: *"The term 'monkey nuts' describes peanuts with the shell or pod intact. "*

Comment: @TC1: Such warnings act as a reminder to an overencumbered mind. Reading it may remind you of the permanent burns that led to the reminder and may prevent further accidents - even if it's just a burnt tongue on french cuisine day.

Comment: @deworde The package didn't say peanuts, it said monkey nuts, and not _everyone_ knows those are peanuts. You say that people with an allergy would surely know, but that warning doesn't necessarily have to be there just for them. It's also for people who might be cooking with it who aren't allergic themselves and are cooking for someone else. They might not know that "monkey nuts" are peanuts.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

A better modification of such a statment which I see being used is:

```
'A company_name employee will never ask for your password'
```

This message alerts the user that if the person is asking for a password, there is something fishy and he should alert the concerned authorities immediately. With all the live chat functionalities that most industries are providing, this is a good safety measure to keep the user informed.

Comment: Not only is this more polite, but it gets to the heart of what the problem actually is (i.e. social engineering, as mentioned by John).

Comment: It is more polite.  But some will interpret that as meaning, they have to provide the password unsolicited.  "How else would the company_name employee log into my account and fix my problem?"

Comment: This is better than some website I used yesterday. I changed my password and got a message that "[company] will never ask you for your password.". Then on the VERY NEXT screen it asked me for my username and password. I know that's not what they meant but ....

Comment: It doesn't have to be pretending to be an employee. In Steam Chat for example, the message is necessary because in Steam's item trading, some people ask for someone's password pretending to need it for the trade, and some people are even stupid enough to give it then. By the way, the message is only shown to new users there, and disappears after a while.

Comment: Funny thing, one of my local hosting companies (czech) actually identify customers by their login-password combination.

Comment: Sprint employees have asked me for my password over the phone multiple times. And every time, I give pause, and ask if there's a different means of identifying myself. My password is my baby.

Comment: @Koviko ideally that would be a red flag in my book.

Answer (score 47):

**Most security breaches are from [social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29)**, and so telling someone that they should never under any circumstances give anyone their password is an attempt to increase security.  I would suggest a statement more like:

> If anyone asks you for your password, you should **assume they are a criminal** and report it immediately!

<sup>Idea provided by @Kaz</sup>

As a more computer savvy person, you may think this goes without saying, but you would be shocked at how many people give their password to other people.  I've even had an old lady at an ATM ask me to help her withdraw money, and before I realised what she was doing, she told me her pin code.

Comment: The people that fall victim to social engineering already "know" they are not supposed to give that information to anyone. They are duped into believing that there is an exception. So the text really has to be a paragraph clearly explaining that under no circumstances will any legitimate agent ever ask for their secret information, and that anyone who does so should be assumed to be a criminal.

Comment: @Kaz Excellent point.  I'm going to borrow the idea in a modified answer.

Comment: That old lady was not all that dumb. She gave her PIN to you, which you didn't ask for. The odds that someone **you** pick to give your PIN to will grab your card and rob your account are much lower than that someone who asks for the PIN will do the same.

Comment: @Kaz It would be nice to think that she thought it through that well :)

Comment: @Kaz I like the way you think about the behavior of the old lady! What a clever granny!

Comment: Note to self:  clean up and hang out around an ATM.  Wait for old lady to approach.  Do not ask for PIN but look helpful.  Confederate will steal her purse at later time.  In this case, I never asked for the password, I just created an environment where the victim felt comfortable sharing it with me.

Answer (score 13):

I was surprised to learn that [teenagers share passwords much more than I expected.](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/01/18/us/teenagers-sharing-passwords-as-show-of-affection.html?pagewanted=all)

So maybe **for some demographics, it is necessary to reinforce more secure behavior**.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with sharing your password with a trusted user - my wife has the passphrase to a password vault where I keep my passwords. Of course, you need to be ready to change those passwords if that "trusted user" becomes untrusted.

Comment: @Johnny You just hope that you change the password before they do :)

Answer (score 7):

**It's a practice perpetuated by corporate legal counsel and made somewhat necessary by our litigious society.** It is silly and slightly insulting but, fortunately, we all do it so we all look equally insulting.

Comment: +1 for being at the heart of the matter. Everything everyone has said is true, but if our society was not so sue happy, and didn't expect every single little instruction to be laid out for them, these types of messages would not be necessary. As indeed they were not that common 50 years ago. Or even 15 years ago...

Comment: How many times have you run up against a UX wall because of legal requirements that do nothing for the customer and little for corporate liability in the end?

Answer (score 7):

### The evils of the modern information age.

Chat programs, e-mail programs, and most non-SSL web pages transfer information back and forth in a [clear text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clear_text) format. This means that it's non-encrypted and readable by anyone with access to the text.

Even though the network your computer is connected to seems like a physical straight connection to the router or switch, or maybe the because you've connected your wireless network adapter to a wireless router or modem, the communications to those devices are not two-way in terms of network traffic. Basically everything on a network goes to everything else, and just like a radio broadcast tower sends out a signal in all directions, so does a wireless network card. The difference is the two items communicating both broadcast to each other with information stating the intended destination. Anything on the network has the potential to log all traffic passively and undetected.

People spend countless hours writing applications that scrape and datamine sites that contain logs of interactions and transcripts of chats looking for information in specific formats. Once a match has been found that information is stored. Also people will sit in public places like coffee shops, airports, and private neighborhoods collecting any information they can from over the airwaves or off of networks. Then later they datamine the collected information for patterns such as username/password combinations, social security numbers, credit card numbers, and even something as simple as email addresses.

### Does it matter?

This day and age most sites will request that your password be at least 8 characters long and contain random characters. This is the same reason your airplane seat cushions float; to quote *Fight Club* "the illusion of safety." [There are machines that can crack passwords extremely fast.](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/) And Social Security numbers are not unique based on the number of people in the country & the number of digits possible in the [Social Security Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Structure). Credit card numbers are equally guessable/calculable.

While it doesn't take a lot of work to write a program to guess any of these numbers it does require several attempts to be able to use a number paired with other information effectively without sending up a red flag. Meaning even though someone guesses your password hash they still need to find out your username. Also they need to provide your name and some sort of identification, plus your social security number before they buy that new car you didn't know you were going to pay for.

This is where the statements "don't share your information with anyone" come into play. Just as most companies are slightly worried about being sued for breach of information, they are extremely afraid of negative PR associated with someone stealing identities on their systems because a chat log, e-mail log, web log, or a router log has been compromised. This is evident by the [large numbers of attorneys](http://www.law.yale.edu/documents/pdf/CDO_Public/Final_LIB_Guide_2011_-_Public.pdf) on the payroll at Fortune 500 companies. They also cover themselves with the Terms of Service.

### What should responsible companies do about it?

1. [Store partial credit card numbers](http://www.networksolutions.com/education/cisp-compliance/) in a database or make people provide their CC#s every time.
2. Delete live logs from the server or router after a short amount of time (after they've been backed up if neccessary)
3. Encrypt backups and logs
4. Immediately strip anything that looks like personal data from a public listing where it looks like someone is sharing personal information.

## How could they go about warning the user?

Other than placing the warning buried in the terms and conditions of the site they should indicate specifically how the information is being used. Here are a few examples.

1. Warning: Everything on this website is public and searchable in a search engine.
2. Providing your personal identification to someone allows them to steal your identity.
3. This website does not screen criminal histories of its users. Be careful when meeting face-to-face.
4. Due to the nature of the internet, online gameplay may not be suitable for children under 18.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely a **"better safe than sorry" tactic**, but I feel that these messages are meant more for the non-tech savvy user.

I've worked with several older clients that are simply unaware of such vulnerabilities.

Ultimately, it also depends on the audience of the site. I doubt github or stack exchange will have such messages.

However, if you're a bank, that may be a different story.

Answer (score 1):

The number of passwords I've been given unsolicited over the years is amazing--yet in almost all cases I make it clear I want the person to do the login themselves rather than giving me the password.  The only time I can recall actually asking for a password was when I didn't want to have to TeamViewer into their system in order to manipulate yet a third system.

To make it worse people's *password breeches can have ripple effects*.  I probably know the email password of every employee of one company.  The passwords are plenty strong against an uninformed attack but from knowing two of them I could guess the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually obvious, as we observe that the chat/ social forums/ or any other site!

1. The sites are free to open an account (in most cases). So any one can open an account with fake details/fake account created on another mail hoster(as only email verification is taken as to avoid unauthorized users). 
   In this case some new users who is new to IT, mostly retired persons(or any good harted person in name of donation may be), do post some sensitive details after few conversations.(alert!!!)
2. The chat basically takes place with the IRC protocol that is not secure in most cases, and the details in chat are easy to trace, track, and store. So, not a good medium either to pass on this kind of detail even if you know the person on other side is goo guy.
3. This is general precaution taken by companies as to avoid the name(defame) in news that using there medium user was affected.

I am not sure if more reasons are there... :)

Answer (score 1):

That statement is kept in its place **mainly for first time users** who haven't yet understood the requirement of a password. Another reason for that would be so that the **owner of the site can avert any responsibility** in case of passwords getting hacked due to reasons other than the obvious security failure of the website. As you may already know, experienced users dont go about sharing their passwords with anyone. You really cant trust anyone these days, even friends, as internet pranks are increasing in number.

Answer (score -1):

**It's a reminder**, in some certain situations *we might forget*, it's better to have it there.

Comment: Tea Nguyen, could you please elaborate giving more information?